# Data Truncation Exception doesn't print column name

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, truncate

I'm using Hibernate 3.0 with SQL Server 2008.

My problem is whenever a Data Truncation exception occurs, it doesn't show column name, which causes this exception. Neither it shows the query being fired with actual values.

For example, I have the following POJO:

**Teacher.java**

```
private long id;
private String name;

// getter-setter of both
```

`name` field is mapped to `name` column.

`name` column is having datatype: `varchar(50)`.

Now if I try to add a record of `Teacher` with name having a String containing more than 50 characters (`session.save(teacher)`), it gives me the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [com.test.Teacher]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.test.TestTeacher.main(TestTeacher.java:1314)
Caused by: java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:382)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:584)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:546)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 16 more
```

As you can see, the above exception doesn't give any kind of informtaion related to column or to data being entered.

I've found the following link: http://www.cereslogic.com/pages/2008/06/10/use-hibernate-validators-to-find-nasty/

But it uses annotations. I'm not using annotations but mapping files.

I've also tried handling the exception & the following:

```
dataTruncation.getIndex();
dataTruncation.getDataSize();
dataTruncation.getTransferSize();
```

But those also don't help, as they all return -1.

Can someone suggest me a suitable way around?